# Why is "104" sorted before "0000105"?

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort the array in php. However, the result is not same as I excepted.

```
$k = ["0000000105","104","A","C","B"];
sort($k);
var_dump($k);
```

I would like to get `0000000105, 104, A,B,C`

However, it sorted like

`104,0000000105, A,B,C`

Why 104 is showing first instead of second ? How to fix it ?

In Swift , I wrote like following and it sorted like excepted result

```
var str = ["0000000105","104","A","C","B"]

let k = str.sorted()

print(k) //0000000105, 104, A,B,C
```

Comment: If you want numeric sorting, then you should ideally be working only with numbers.  You could remove the leading zeroes and then sort, and it should give you the result you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if OP removed the leading zeros, `105` still comes after `104`

Comment: Why **exactly** would you expect `0000000105` to come **before** `104`?

Comment: @Phil Most languages that sort *strictly as string* would put "099" before "1". See in JavaScript: `["1","099"].sort();`.

Comment: @Phil because it's a string. I tested with Swift (updated in answer). However results is not same and cannot do hash match anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the elements strictly as strings, you need to tell PHP to do so, ie

```
sort($k, SORT_STRING);
```

PHP is a loosely typed language so when it encounters `0000000105` and `104`, it will compare them numerically when using `SORT_REGULAR`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `natsort($k);`

the result will be

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(10) "0000000105" [1]=> string(3) "104" [2]=> string(1) "A" [4]=> string(1) "B" [3]=> string(1) "C" }
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? From 5.2.10 ~ *"Zero padded numeric strings (e.g., '00005') now essentially ignore the 0 padding."*

Comment: The diffrence between `sort($k, SORT_STRING)` and `natsort($k)` is that `natsort($k)` does not change indexes in array

Comment: I'm acually using php version 5.2